# Position of the adverb: "The package was promptly sent" or "The package was sent promptly"?

Tags: adverb-placement

What is the correct (or preferred) position of the adverb: before the verb (past participle) or after the verb (past participle)?

More specifically, which of the following is correct (or preferred)?

1. **"The package was promptly sent."** [*before* the verb (past participle)]
2. **"The package was sent promptly."** [*after* the verb (past participle)]

Do (1) and (2) differ in meaning at all, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Oxford Dictionaries says that *promptly* can be 'used to express surprise, and slight disapproval, when someone does something shortly after something else'.

So, I would understand *The package was promptly sent to [place]* to imply that it had been forwarded to somewhere else when the speaker wishes it hadn't been.

*The package was sent promptly* - it was sent in good time to arrive at its destination.

Comment: *The worker was promptly sent home* // *The worker was sent promptly home* I see little to no difference in meaning without further context.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I don't find _The worker was sent promptly home_ idiomatic anyway.